# Numbers in a sequence 0

Tags: sequences-and-series

a sequence:

$ 2; \frac{1}{2}; \frac{4}{3}; \frac{3}{4}; \frac{6}{5}; ... $

expressed n terms of the formula?

I can not understand then alternating even and odd, and how to record a sequence of n member

Comment: Do you have any information as to the type of sequence it is (arithmetic, geometric, linear, etc...) or what this sequence is meant to describe (does it count something)?  Unless more information is given, it is generally impossible to answer a "what comes next in the sequence" question as there is no way of knowing *which* of infinitely many possible sequences this is referring to.  Maybe the next unwritten number is $\frac{5}{6}$, or maybe the next unwritten number is $85.4\pi$, or perhaps even $10^{10^{150}}+2$.

Comment: no,
task sounds:
a sequence of (...) an expression for the Un

Comment: Well, most likely it is a sequence of numbers

Answer (score 3):

One **possible** pattern that it could follow is that the denominator always increases by one at each step and the numerator is either one higher than the denominator or one smaller than the denominator depending on the parity of the term.

If that were the case, then the sequence with the next several terms will look like:

$$2,\frac{1}{2},\frac{4}{3},\frac{3}{4},\frac{6}{5},\frac{5}{6},\frac{8}{7},\frac{7}{8},\dots$$

In order to write the arbitrary term of **this** sequence (*which may or may not be the intended sequence*) as you notice,  you need to account for whether or not the location of the term in the sequence is even or odd.  There are a number of ways of dealing with this.

- Define the pattern in a piecewise-fashion

For example: $f(n)=\begin{cases} ...&\text{if}~n~\text{is even}\\
...&\text{if}~n~\text{is odd}\end{cases}$

- Add or multiply by a cyclic term whose output depends on the parity of $n$

For example: $f(n)=n+(-1)^n$ or $g(n)=n+\sin(\frac{n\pi}{2})$

As the patterns get more complicated, you may need to get creative and mix&match tactics such as these in order to achieve the desired result.

In the sequence **I** describe, you could write it in any of the following ways:

$f(n)=\begin{cases} \frac{n+1}{n}&\text{if}~n~\text{is odd}\\ \frac{n-1}{n}&~\text{if}~n~\text{is even}\end{cases}$

$f(n)=\frac{n-(-1)^n}{n}$

$f(n)= 1-(-1)^n\frac{1}{n}$

and more...

---

**HOWEVER**

There is **no** way of knowing what the intended sequence actually is without more information.

Take for example, the sequence $1,1,2,3,5,8,13,\dots$.

If I were to ask you what the next number in the sequence is, perhaps you might be inclined to say that the next number is $21$ since it appears to be simply adding the previous two numbers to get the next number (The famous Fibonacci sequence).

I could have been mean however and intended the answer to be $39$ instead.

$1,1,2,3,5,8,13,39,124,514,\dots$

the rule instead being to add the *reversal of the digits of the previous two numbers* to get the next one (The lesser known Iccanobif sequence).

Comment: More seriously, my favorite example of this is the (maximum possible) number of partitions of a circle created by $n$ points on the circumference and all chords extending between them.  $C_1 = 1$ (the whole circle), $C_2 = 2, C_3 = 4, C_4 = 8, C_5 = 16$.  And so on, right?  But $C_6 = 31$.